# Node Express Kraken routing windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, kraken.js

Hi I am using kraken with express on node app. I am facing problem on windows. I have a route eg 'register/:appname?' and appname is a optional param. Since kraken (as I understand well) foces directory structure for this controller it should look like this: controllers->register->:appname? am I right? If yes, this is an issue on windows because we cannot create folders with "?"

Answer (score 0):

try `controllers\register.js`, with something like this:

```
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/:appname?', function (req, res) {
    });
}
```

Or `controllers\index.js` with this:

```
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/register/:appname?', function (req, res) {
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Parameters in the URL are not part of the directory structure.  Taking from Aredridel's example above you would do something like this:

```
module.exports = function (router) {
    router.get('/register/:appname?', function (req, res) {
        var app_name = req.params.appname ? req.params.appname: '';
    });
};
```